# urls getting confusing when display json result using jquery

Tags: facebook, json, url, rss

HTML code:

```
<a id="" onmouseover="LinkshimAsyncLink.swap(this, "http:\/\/www.tbogard.com\/2008\/05\/31\/tutorial-how-to-jsonp-with-jquery-using-getjson-or-ajax\/");" rel="nofollow" style="" onclick="LinkshimAsyncLink.swap(this, "http:\/\/www.facebook.com\/l.php?u=http\u00253A\u00252F\u00252Fwww.tbogard.com\u00252F2008\u00252F05\u00252F31\u00252Ftutorial-how-to-jsonp-with-jquery-using-getjson-or-ajax\u00252F&h=CAQFB81hM&s=1");" target="" title="" href="http://www.facebook.com/l.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.tbogard.com%2F2008%2F05%2F31%2Ftutorial-how-to-jsonp-with-jquery-using-getjson-or-ajax%2F&h=CAQFB81hM&s=1">
    <img class="img" alt="" src="https://fbexternal-a.akamaihd.net/safe_image.php?d=AQDDROkII35SUCO7&w=90&h=90&url=http%3A%2F%2Fi2.wp.com%2Fwww.tbogard.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2010%2F10%2Frjson.jpg%3Ffit%3D400%2C400">
    </a>
    <br>
    <a id="" onmouseover="LinkshimAsyncLink.swap(this, "http:\/\/www.tbogard.com\/2008\/05\/31\/tutorial-how-to-jsonp-with-jquery-using-getjson-or-ajax\/");" rel="nofollow" style="" onclick="LinkshimAsyncLink.swap(this, "http:\/\/www.facebook.com\/l.php?u=http\u00253A\u00252F\u00252Fwww.tbogard.com\u00252F2008\u00252F05\u00252F31\u00252Ftutorial-how-to-jsonp-with-jquery-using-getjson-or-ajax\u00252F&h=wAQFEyL2-&s=1");" target="_blank" href="http://www.facebook.com/l.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.tbogard.com%2F2008%2F05%2F31%2Ftutorial-how-to-jsonp-with-jquery-using-getjson-or-ajax%2F&h=wAQFEyL2-&s=1">Tutorial : How to JSONP with jQuery using $.getJSON or $.ajax</a>
    <br>
    www.tbogard.com
    <br>
    Remote Services is a now-a-day need, and sadly few documented in detail. Here you can learn how to use Remote JSON (JSONP) In your web-applications with jQuery, PHP and
```

[image]

i got above source codes using firebug. here is my [page](http://www.doers.lk/), when i click some URL in the site it says bellow error message in the facebook.
[image]

I get the facebook page feeds via json with yql api support. But what i want is when i click some urls in my site like this

```
www.tbogard.com
```

it will link to the given url without accessing facebook. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: The target URL is right there in the Facebook URL, as parameter called `u` - so just extract that and replace the original URL with it.

Comment: how? can you give me your code ?